# IDC: Get structure id under cursor in "Structures" window?

Tags: ida, idapython

I'm writing an IDC script which accepts a structure and does some processing. Currently, I have to call it by typing structure names. What I want is to make it use the structure under cursor in "Structures" window so I can save a lot of typing. Is there any way to do this?

Tried `ScreenEA()`. It returns the address in "Disassembly" window instead of a structure id.

IDAPython code is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be bit of an odd question - but how do you run the script? Hotkeys don't work while the structure view is open, and if you run a script via `Alt+F7` for example the cursor position changes.

That said, one solution that may be good enough:

```
import ida_kernwin

ret = ida_kernwin.get_highlight(ida_kernwin.get_current_widget())
if ret and ret[1]:
    print "Current highlight: %s" % ret[0]
```

Basically, you need to click the structure name so it's highlighted (yellow), then the above code will print the struct name.

Comment: I use IDA 6.8 and IDAPython v1.7.2. In my case the spell is `idaapi.get_highlighted_identifier()`.